# How to remove TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'vectorize' , vectorize, astype not working

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook

I want to display a bar graph comparing y and yHat( both arrays holding three values each
), It's showing errors despite using vectorize and astype(float)

```
plt.bar([0.35,1.35,2.35],np.vectorize(yHat.astype(float)), width = 0.35, color='r', alpha=0.8)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['y(expected)','yHat(recieved)'])
'''
TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-343a5f511526> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.bar([0.00,1.00,2.00], np.vectorize(y.astype(float)), width = 0.35, alpha=0.8)
      2 plt.bar([0.35,1.35,2.35],np.vectorize(yHat.astype(float)), width = 0.35, color='r', alpha=0.8)
      3 plt.grid(True)
      4 plt.legend(['y(expected)','yHat(recieved)'])

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/patches.py in __init__(self, xy, width, height, angle, **kwargs)
    714 
    715         self._x1 = self._x0 + self._width
--> 716         self._y1 = self._y0 + self._height
    717 
    718         self.angle = float(angle)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'vectorize'
```

Comment: you should not vectorize, instead use the arrays as they are

Comment: That was initially how I did it, it shows TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: then make your arrays same size, not vectorize

Comment: they are both of the same size.

Comment: then sth else is wrong, again vectorize has nothing to do with that. [here is the matplotlib doc for bar charts](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)

Comment: what is the shape of these arrays, maybe they are 2-dimensional. I see no other problem

Comment: oh god, thanks, all I had to do was flatten the arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot that the arrrays weren't 1-D, all I had to do was flatten them using **.flatten()**

```
    plt.bar(([0.00,1.00,2.00]), (y.flatten()), width = 0.35,  bottom=None,align='edge', color='r',data=None)
    plt.bar(([0.35,1.35,2.35]),(yHat.flatten()), width = 0.35, bottom=None,align='edge', color='b',data=None)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend(['y(expected)','yHat(recieved)'])
```